# VBA : Get structure fields number

Tags: vba, types, structure

In VBA, I have created a structure using the "type" statement. Is it possible to get the number of fields of my structure ?
For example I have the following structure.

```
Type st_ABC
    a as Integer
    b as Integer
    c as Integer
End Type
```

From this structure, I would like to get the number of fields (3 in this example), is it possible ?

Comment: Very hard to see why you would want to do that, what's it for? - there is likely a better approach.  That said In your example where they are all integers: `Dim T As st_ABC, i as Integer: memberCount = LenB(T) / LenB(i)`

Comment: I'd suggest turning it into a class module that exposes the fields as public, and you can provide a method (such as `.NumberOfFields`) that will give you the value. Easy to maintain.